# Wordpress is not displaying unapproved comments

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress is not showing comments in a 'hold' status i.e 'waiting for moderation'.

That is after posting comments in a post it should show 'Your comment is awaiting moderation'.

But after posting a comment and refreshing the page,nothing is shown in the comments section.

We are using wordpress standard theme.

File comments.php from theme twentyfifteen

Answer (score 0):

Did you fill author's email field? Wordpress shows unapproved comments owned by commentor, however uses commenter's email to detect its ownership.

at wp-includes/comment-template.php:1999 (ver 4.7.3) : `$comment_args['include_unapproved'] = $commenter['comment_author_email'];`